# Loop crashes with Falco

Tags: docker, security, kubernetes, falco

I'm currently experimenting with Falco (a runtime monitoring solution for container).
I'm working locally on a Mac (Catalina v10.15.3), have Helm (v3.1.2) installed, Docker (version 2.2.0.5 (43884)) and K8s running (v1.15.5).

I try deploying Falco using helm as suggest in their [installation page](https://falco.org/docs/installation/) and I end up in a loop of crash for the pod.
Here are the logs that I get :

```
$ kubectl logs falco-xxxxx
* Setting up /usr/src links from host
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/src//host/usr/src/*': No such file or directory
* Unloading falco-probe, if present
* Running dkms install for falco
Error! echo
Your kernel headers for kernel 4.19.76-linuxkit cannot be found at
/lib/modules/4.19.76-linuxkit/build or /lib/modules/4.19.76-linuxkit/source.
* Running dkms build failed, couldn't find /var/lib/dkms/falco/0.20.0+d77080a/build/make.log
* Trying to load a system falco-probe, if present
* Trying to find precompiled falco-probe for 4.19.76-linuxkit
Found kernel config at /proc/config.gz
* Trying to download precompiled module from https://s3.amazonaws.com/download.draios.com/stable/sysdig-probe-binaries/falco-probe-0.20.0%2Bd77080a-x86_64-4.19.76-linuxkit-f9de4c19ddd4080798f0e14972190e35.ko
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Download failed, consider compiling your own falco-probe and loading it or getting in touch with the Falco community
Thu Apr  2 15:39:47 2020: Falco initialized with configuration file /etc/falco/falco.yaml
Thu Apr  2 15:39:47 2020: Loading rules from file /etc/falco/falco_rules.yaml:
Thu Apr  2 15:39:48 2020: Loading rules from file /etc/falco/falco_rules.local.yaml:
Thu Apr  2 15:39:49 2020: Unable to load the driver. Exiting.
Thu Apr  2 15:39:49 2020: Runtime error: error opening device /dev/falco0. Make sure you have root credentials and that the falco-probe module is loaded.. Exiting.
```

I looked around a bit and didn't find a clue so I took the liberty to ask directly here before trying to compile the probe myself.

Do you have any idea how to fix this issue ?

Comment: This is a know problem when running it on mac. You can check [this](https://github.com/falcosecurity/falco/issues/690) issue and a possible workaround [here](https://github.com/falcosecurity/falco/issues/657#issuecomment-506303851).

Comment: Thanks for the links, the second one was promissing, however after building the container, when I try to launch it, it crash on the CMD command of the Dockerfile with this log `$ docker run -it --rm --privileged falco-docker4win:latest
insmod: can't insert '/sysdig/build/driver/sysdig-probe.ko': invalid module format`.